# String interpolation in Groovy from file data

Tags: groovy

## Question

I have the following xml

```
<m cid='${cid}' pwd='${pwd}' rid='' subunitid='${unitid}'>
    <call>
        <arg name='statusid'>1</arg>
    </call>
</m>
```

In groovy I have the following code

```
def cid = 316
def pwd = 'abc12'
def subunitid = 123

def xml = """
    <m cid='${cid}' pwd='${pwd}' rid='' subunitid='${unitid}'>
        <call>
            <arg name='statusid'>1</arg>
        </call>
    </m>
"""
```

Through Groovy's string interpolation syntax this swaps out the cid, pwd, and unitid variable with the value assigned to that variable.

However, I want to store this xml in a file and load from the file.  When I use the following Groovy it does not perform String interpolation

```
def xml = new File('request.xml').text;
```

What is the Grooviest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the "grooviest" part : ) but the following code:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def binding  = [cid: 316, pwd: 'abc12', unitid: 123]
def template = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(new File('request.xml'))
def result   = template.make(binding).toString()

println result
```

when executed, will print:

```
─➤ cat request.xml 
<m cid='${cid}' pwd='${pwd}' rid='' subunitid='${unitid}'>
  <call>
    <arg name='statusid'>1</arg>
  </call>
</m>

─➤ groovy solution.groovy 
<m cid='316' pwd='abc12' rid='' subunitid='123'>
  <call>
    <arg name='statusid'>1</arg>
  </call>
</m>

─➤
```